# yii - '"php.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: php, yii

I tried to install  yii framework. I follow the steps as mentioned in the installation guide, but in command window i was getting this error :
“php.exe”' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
Environmental Variables:C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16;C:\wamp\www\yii\framework

Comment: Do you have PHP installed on your system?

Comment: add php.exe directory to the environment variable

Comment: ok, but there is no php.exe file in side that folder

Comment: Can you load a normal PHP file on your localhost?

Comment: i was added but it showing again same error.

Comment: yes, php files working in localhost @random

Comment: you have to add php.exe to your local system variables

Comment: like this i added: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php.exe; is it correct..but its not working same error i was getting

Comment: add without exe and make sure there is semi colon before the path like this  ;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\;

Comment: same error i m getting

Answer (score 0):

just install xampp, all works out of the box http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html